# Fill in Ending Balance from previous months balance

Tags: update, query

I need to fill in the Ending Balance of each Year / Period where it is 0 (zero) but a previous period for that year and company has an ending balance - basically carrying forward the ending balance for that company for the year.

This may be less complicated that I makiang it to be , but I can get my TEMP table all the way down to this, but need an update statement

reviewing the attached below

(In Yellow) Company 400 - Period 01 has an ending balance of -35460601.79, this needs to be that beginning balance of company 400 - Period 02 and then that Period 02 beginning balance is to set as the Period 02 Ending balance - then moving down through Company 400 until you get to a new Company/Fiscalyear.

Company 401 is good and no action is required

Company 500 needs to do what Company 400 did but Company 500 starts at Period 04/05 - filling down until it reaches the next company.
This will process will step the entire table By Year / By Company
I really appreciate your expertise in helping me
Stephen

[image]

Comment: What version of which RDMBS?

Comment: [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: MSSQL 2017 is the version I am running